# ORDER BY, Desconsiderar demais colunas (ou considerar apenas a coluna informada)

Tags: oracle

Tenho uma tabela de produtos com Valor de Venda de cada item.
Ao executar um ORDER BY na coluna 'Valor de Venda' parece que ele está ordenando dentro de cada produto.
Preciso que seja ordenado por Valor de Venda independente dos demais itens.

Código utilizado:

```
SELECT PROD.CODPROD, PROD.DESCRPROD, EXC.CONTROLE, EXC.VLRVENDA
FROM TAB_PROD PROD, TAB_PRECO EXC
WHERE PROD.CODPROD = EXC.CODPROD
ORDER BY EXC.VLRVENDA DESC
```

Resultado:
[image: Resultado da Query:]

Obs: Se no ORDER BY alterar para ASC, os valores são ordenados porém dentro de cada código de produto.

Preciso ordenar a coluna VlrVenda em ordem decrescente, independente do produto.

Resultado esperado:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: já tentou substituir o WHERE que liga as tabelas por um JOIN convencional?

Comment: Impossível , certo de ser mesma sql e resultado ?!